# Can you use Brillo Pads to get slight build up of carbon on spark plugs?

Tags: honda, accord, sparkplugs

Honda Accord 1999 1.8 injection

Can you use Brillo Pads to get slight build up of carbon on spark plugs?

Answer (score 2):

I would just replace them for my **vehicle**, but for my yearly lawnmower tune-up, some brakeKleen solvent, **gentle** cleaning with steel brush, and emery cloth on the electrode until shiny(*2 swipes?*) has always worked! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Brillo pads leave dusty, fibrous residue when used. As long as all of it is removed before reinstalling the spark plug in the cylinder, it should be acceptable to use it.

Answer (score 0):

To properly clean spark plugs your local garage may have a media blasting plug cleaner.. However you can do almost as good a job with a wire brush.. No need for any chemicals etc. The wire brush will get rid of most deposits and leave the plugs in a very usable condition.

Answer (score 0):

A brillo pad and a wire brush have a similar problem - they don't clean right down in the "valley"  between the body and the insulator.

The sparkplug cleaner / test machine will clean that area and will be able to test the sparkplug for insulation effectiveness under pressure as well.